# Is it possible to animate a useState in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

I would like to know how I can animate some Views in react native using a useState, for example i made this code:

```
import { useState } from "react"
import { View, Button, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const [step, setStep] = useState(0)

  return (
    <View>
      {
        step == 0 ?
        <View style={style.container}>
          <Text>Step 1</Text>
          <Button title="Next" onPress={() => setStep(1)} />
        </View>
        : step == 1 ?
        <View style={style.container}>
          <Text>Step 2</Text>
          <Button title="Next" onPress={() => setStep(2)} />
        </View>
        : step == 2 ?
        <View style={style.container}>
          <Text>Step 3</Text>
          <Button title="Next" onPress={() => setStep(3)} />
        </View>
        :
        <></>
      }
    </View>
  );
}


const style = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  }
})
```

And the idea is that when you click on the next button, a slide animation is made to the next View

I explore react native reanimated but I can't find a part in the documentation that allows me to do it with a useState, does anyone have an idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

To get what you want, you should use animation. In React Native, you can also find the Animated API to help you with this. Instead of using `useState`, you will use `Animated.Value` to decide which View to display.